# Getting `ld: directory not found for option` build error after installing cocoa pod

Tags: xcode, build, continuous-integration, cocoapods, xcodebuild

I installed a new cocoa pod (LaunchDarkly) for my Xcode project, but I'm getting the following error in my CI server when trying to build the project:

```
⚠️  ld: directory not found for option '-F/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-hlaqakonueydmsgzoxgekwjpjyds/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/LDSwiftEventSource'

⚠️  ld: directory not found for option '-F/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-hlaqakonueydmsgzoxgekwjpjyds/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/LaunchDarkly'

❌  ld: framework not found LDSwiftEventSource
❌  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the issue was that I was still building the `.xcodeproj` file as shown below:

```
xcodebuild build-for-testing
        -project ProjectName.xcodeproj
        -scheme ProjectName
        -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 12,OS=latest'
        -testPlan UnitTests
        | xcpretty
```

But since I was now using cocoa pods in my project, I needed to use the `.xcworkspace file` to build it:

```
xcodebuild build-for-testing
        -workspace ProjectName.xcworkspace
        -scheme ProjectName
        -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 12,OS=latest'
        -testPlan UnitTests
        | xcpretty
```